# Question about Conditional Expectation and Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, analysis, stochastic-processes

I have been struggling with this problem for quite some time. Suppose $B_t$ is the standard Brownian motion, then let $X_t= e^{B_t}$. I calculated the expectation as $$E[X_t]=e^{t^2/2}$$ and the variance as $$Var[X_t]=e^{t^2}[e^{t^2}-1]$$ I believe these are the correct solutions, but I am not absolutely sure and if they are incorrect, I would like to go into more detail about how I found those solutions to get some feedback, but in the interest of time, the more pressing part is that I am meant to calculate $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}E[\frac{f(X_{t+h})-f(X_t)}{h}|X_t=x]$$ With f assumed to be nice enough (I assume nice enough to swap the integral and the limit). I have attempted this problem several times. I used the form of $X_t$ and Taylor Thm. to write: $$X_{t+h}=e^{B_t}+e^{B_t}(B_{t+h}-B_t)+\frac{1}{2}e^{B_t}(B_{t+h}-B_t)^2+...$$
So we have $$f(X_{t+h})-f(X_t)=f'(X_t)(X_{t+h}-X_t)+\frac{1}{2}f''(X_t)(X_{t+h}-X_t)^2+...$$
$$=f'(X_t)(e^{B_t}(B_{t+h}-B_t)+\frac{1}{2}e^{B_t}(B_{t+h}-B_t)^2+...)+\frac{1}{2}f''(X_t)(e^{B_t}(B_{t+h}-B_t)+\frac{1}{2}e^{B_t}(B_{t+h}-B_t)^2+...)^2+...$$

By assumption $B_{t+h}-B_t \sim N(0,h).$ So to me it seems like the first term should get wiped out in the average. $E[(B_{t+h}-B_t)^2]=Var[B_{t+h}-B_t]+E[B_{t+h}-B_t]^2=h.$ So this term should survive in the average as $\frac{1}{2}xf'(x).$

I have a couple questions at this point.

1) Is what I've done correct so far?

2) Are there more surviving terms?

3) What did I just compute. What does it mean? It's clearly some kind of derivative, but why use this particular process?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Is what I've done correct so far?

Your results for expectation and variance seem incorrect. Provided that $B_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,t)$ with $t$ being its variance, the correct results should be
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}X_t&=\mathbb{E}e^{B_t}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-x^2/\left(2t\right)}{\rm d}x=e^{t/2},\\
\mathbb{D}X_t&=\mathbb{E}X_t^2-\left(\mathbb{E}X_t\right)^2=\mathbb{E}e^{2B_t}-\left(\mathbb{E}e^{B_t}\right)^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{2x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-x^2/\left(2t\right)}{\rm d}x-e^t=e^t\left(e^t-1\right).
\end{align}
I am afraid you have taken $t$ as $t^2$ by mistake.

Your result for limit happens to be incomplete. The correct limit should be
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(xf'(x)+x^2f''(x)\right).
$$
I am afraid you have left out the $f''(x)$ term, which has been included in the second step from the last in your derivation.

> 2) Are there more surviving terms?

Your expansion to the quadratic term is indeed a wise choice. I am not sure if you have in mind [Ito calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus), especially [Ito's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma), but keeping the quadratic terms coincides with the concept of [quadratic variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation). Therefore, no more term would survive with mathematical rigor (here I assume that you did not leave out the $f''(x)$ term by mistake).

> What did I just compute. What does it mean?

As is mentioned above, you were re-deriving the quadratic variation of standard Brownian motion.

To make your derivations mathematically rigorous, I will be following the schematic way to restate your result. First of all,
\begin{align}
\frac{f(X_{t+h})-f(X_t)}{h}&=\frac{1}{h}\int_{s\in\left[0,h\right]}{\rm d}f(X_{t+s})\\
&=\frac{1}{h}\int_{s\in\left[0,h\right]}\left(f'(X_{t+s}){\rm d}X_{t+s}+\frac{1}{2}f''(X_{t+s}){\rm d}\left<X\right>_{t+s}\right),
\end{align}
where we have used Ito's lemma
$$
{\rm d}g(Y_t)=g'(Y_t){\rm d}Y_t+\frac{1}{2}g''(Y_t){\rm d}\left<Y\right>_t
$$
with $\left<Y\right>_t$ being the quadratic variation of $Y_t$.

Thereafter, since $X_t=e^{B_t}$, Ito's lemma yields
$$
{\rm d}X_t={\rm d}e^{B_t}=e^{B_t}{\rm d}B_t+\frac{1}{2}e^{B_t}{\rm d}\left<B\right>_t=e^{B_t}{\rm d}B_t+\frac{1}{2}e^{B_t}{\rm d}t,
$$
where we have used $\left<B\right>_t=t$. This relation, as per the [fundamental identity](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/properties-of-quadratic-variations/#scn_qvprop_thm7), reveals that
$$
{\rm d}\left<X\right>_t=\left(e^{B_t}\right)^2{\rm d}\left<B\right>_t=e^{2B_t}{\rm d}t.
$$

With these results, we eventually obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{f(X_{t+h})-f(X_t)}{h}&=\frac{1}{h}\int_{s\in\left[0,h\right]}\left[f'(X_{t+s})\left(e^{B_{t+s}}{\rm d}B_{t+s}+\frac{1}{2}e^{B_{t+s}}{\rm d}s\right)+\frac{1}{2}f''(X_{t+s})e^{2B_{t+s}}{\rm d}s\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{h}\int_{s\in\left[0,h\right]}\left[H_{t+s}{\rm d}B_{t+s}+\frac{1}{2}\left(f'(X_{t+s})e^{B_{t+s}}+f''(X_{t+s})e^{2B_{t+s}}\right){\rm d}s\right],
\end{align}
where $H_{t+s}=f'(X_{t+s})e^{B_{t+s}}$.

Define
$$
Z_t=\int_0^tH_s{\rm d}B_s.
$$
Since $B_t$ is a [martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)), according to Ito calculus, $Z_t$, as a stochastic integral of a martingale, is also a martingale. Note that
$$
\int_{s\in\left[0,h\right]}H_{t+s}{\rm d}B_{t+s}=Z_{t+h}-Z_t.
$$
As per the definition of martingale, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(Z_{t+h}-Z_t|\mathcal{F}_t\right)=0,
$$
where $\mathcal{F}_t$ means the given information no later than the moment $t$ (provided that $X_t=x$, $B_t$ is known as well; so are $H_t$ and $Z_t$).

Consequently,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{f(X_{t+h})-f(X_t)}{h}\Bigg|X_t\right)=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{2h}\int_{s\in\left[0,h\right]}\left(f'(X_{t+s})e^{B_{t+s}}+f''(X_{t+s})e^{2B_{t+s}}\right){\rm d}s\Bigg|X_t\right].
$$
For simplicity, define
$$
g(x)=xf'(x)+x^2f''(x).
$$
With this definition, the last result witnesses further simplification
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{f(X_{t+h})-f(X_t)}{h}\Bigg|X_t\right)=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{2h}\int_{s\in\left[0,h\right]}g(X_{t+s}){\rm d}s\Bigg|X_t\right]=\frac{1}{2h}\int_0^h\mathbb{E}\left(g(X_{t+s})|X_t\right){\rm d}s.
$$
Since $\mathbb{E}\left(g(X_{t+s})|X_t\right)$ is no more than a function of $s$, denote
$$
\alpha(s)=\mathbb{E}\left(g(X_{t+s})|X_t\right).
$$
Thus
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{f(X_{t+h})-f(X_t)}{h}\Bigg|X_t\right)=\frac{1}{2h}\int_0^h\alpha(s){\rm d}s.
$$

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0^+}\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{f(X_{t+h})-f(X_t)}{h}\Bigg|X_t\right)&=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1}{2h}\int_0^h\alpha(s){\rm d}s\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\alpha(0)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left(g(X_t)|X_t\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}g(x)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(xf'(x)+x^2f''(x)\right).
\end{align}

I hope these could be helpful for you.